# Expo.GLView doesn't work on iOS when modify app.js file

Tags: javascript, expo

I am currently working on Web AR with expo from my iOS device. During the initial progress, Expo.GLView appears to not work on my iOS when I modified my app.js.

Can anyone help?

```js
import React from 'react';
import Expo from 'expo';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import * as THREE from 'three';
import ExpoTHREE from 'expo-three';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Expo.GLView
        style={{flex: 1}}
        onContextCreate={this._onGLContextCreate}
        />

    );
  }

  _onGLContextCreate = async (gl) => {
    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, gl.drawingBufferWidth / gl.drawingBufferHeight, 0.1, 1000);
    const renderer = ExpoTHREE.createRenderer({ gl });
    renderer.setSize(gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);

    const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
    const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(cube);
    camera.position.z = 5;

    const animate = () => {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
      gl.endFrameEXP();
    }
    animate();
  }
}
```

This is the error that I encounter. I've followed the instructions clearly prior. What is happening?

```
[01:45:27] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_expo.default.GLView')
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like just a minor syntax issue on the import. Expo must have a default export separate from its various components or something like that. The below works for me:

```
import { GLView } from 'expo'
```

I'm currently using expo-three and using the package expo-graphics for my GLView element, I find it a little bit handier as it accepts additional props for "onResize" and "onRender" so you don't need to handle those separately.

```
npm i --save expo-graphics
```

then instead of importing it from expo, import it from expo graphics (the component is just called "view" in expo-graphics, so you may want to import it with its own name if you're working with other views in the same component)

```
import { View as GraphicsView } from 'expo-graphics'
```

Then it's a drop-in replacement for the standard GLView

```
  render() {
    return (
        <GraphicsView
        style={{flex: 1}}
        onContextCreate={this._onGLContextCreate}
        />
    );
  }
```

You can then also add your render loop function and resize function through their respective props

```
  render() {
    return (
        <GraphicsView
        style={{flex: 1}}
        onContextCreate={this._onGLContextCreate}
        onResize={this._onResize}
        onRender={this._onRender}
        />
    );
  }
```